# Symfony issue with editing collection of forms, tag system

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to make tag system, every article could have multiple tags, I'm based on Symfony's documentation [How to Embed a collection of forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Here's my Article entity:

```
<?php

namespace DEERCMS\ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PTB\ArticleBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{

    /...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="string", length=255)
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="DEERCMS\ArticleBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->addTask($this);

        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->remove($tag);
    }

    /**
     * Set tags
     *
     * @param string $tags
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And tag entity

```
<?php

namespace DEERCMS\ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DEERCMS\ArticleBundle\Repository\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

ArticleType:

```
        $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('article', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('img',  FileType::class, array('label' => 'Zdjęcie do artykułu (img)', 'data_class' => null))
        ->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => TagType::class,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                   ));
```

And a TagType.php

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'nazwa tagu')
    ))
;
```

And when I Add article to the database the Tag column looks like this:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@0000000052786f600000000016ee1beb
```

And the table Tag is empty. When I'm trying to edit Article i get error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    $originalTags = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($article->getTags() as $tag) {
        $originalTags->add($tag);
    }
```

So what's wrong with this code? I've tried to find a solution for days and still no progress